# Get the Intent that woke up my activity

Tags: android

I'm developing an application that includes a broadcast receiver.
The broadcast receiver sets a notification onReceive(), which includes a pending Intent

```
Intent updateHistoryIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationsHistory.class);
updateHistoryIntent.putExtra("test", 3);
PendingIntent updateHistoryPendingIntent 
    = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, updateHistoryIntent, 0);

Notification notification 
    = new Notification(icon, contentTitle, System.currentTimeMillis());
notification.setLatestEventInfo(
   context, contentTitle, 
   contentText, updateHistoryPendingIntent
);
```

In the NotificationsHistory Activity, I am receiving this Intent in onResume() with:

```
int testInt = this.getIntent().getIntExtra("test", -1);
Aux.log("test : " + testInt);
```

which prints:

- 3: when the activity was destroyed
- -1: when the activity was sleeping

If I read the docs correctly, `this.getIntent()` will return the Intent that initially started the Activity and the behavior I described is as expected.

So my question is: **How can I get the Intent that woke up my activity?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> when the activity was sleeping

Activities don't sleep. I am assuming that you mean that the activity was in the background.

> How can I get the Intent that woke up my activity?

Add `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` as flags to your `Intent`. Then, your activity will get this `Intent` passed to it via [`onNewIntent()`](http://goo.gl/UQEIC).

Comment: many thanks; worked great (esp. in combination with: 
`protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent){setIntent(intent);}` )

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that when an activity is woken, getIntent() returns the intent that first started it.