# how to keep track of changes to restart the activitiy in android?

Tags: java, android, events, chaining

In my android app, I have activities that are for read only data, and then buttons that take to a new activity where you can edit the data from another activities. The longest chain can be more than 3 or 4 button presses to take them into various kinds of activities where they can see and edit the data.

The main problem is for example, in activities `A`, I can see profile data, then if I click a button, I go to activities `EA` to edit the data from activities `A`. When I save from `EA`, I go back to activities `A`, and then I would need to refresh the data by just restarting the activity.

I can do simple checks for this when its just 1 button involved, but in my app, I have things like `A` goes to `B` goes to `C` and then `EC` (editing data for activities `C`). How can I keep restarting the activities back to where I started if I clicked save in `EC`? So if I saved in `EC`, then as I click back, it needs to restart `C`, then `B`, then `A` during their on resume events. Also the onresume event shouldn't happen if they just minimize the app and then open it up again, because then it would restart for no reason.

Does anyone have any good way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you confusing Views and Activities?  Please check your question and edit if you need to.  I'm confused by your description of "going back to a view".

Comment: Yes I mean activities.

Comment: Im now thinking to store the class objects in a global list as I click new buttons, then when I click save, I just restart all the objects in that list, then remove them all from the list.

Comment: There is still a lot of confusion in here.  `Also the onresume event shouldn't happen if they just minimize the app and then open it up again, because then it would restart for no reason`.  There is no such thing as "minimize" and `onResume()` will be called whenever an activity is brought back to the foreground.  It's entirely up to you what you do in onResume().  If you only want something to happen when the Activity is created, then do it in onCreate().  If you want it to happen every time the Activity comes to the foreground, use onResume() or onStart().

Comment: What does `I would need to refresh the data by just restarting the activity.` mean?

Comment: Well, I need a to differentiate between resuming when another activity just ended (restart should happen here only), and resuming when you start up the app again after pressing the home button to go back to main phone screen.
Also when I say refresh by restart, the app gets the data from a sql database, so when I make changes from another activity, I save it to the DB, then when the previous activity is resumed, I just restart it so it would get the new data from the DB.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089698/get-the-intent-that-woke-up-my-activity and http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Answer (score 0):

I would store the data in a SQLite-Database.

Comment: I am already doing that, but I dont know how that would help.

Comment: I'm not sure if I got your problem. You want to store changes the user made and show them across different activities - but you have a problem keeping the shown data the actual data. 

(Edit): My Solution would be: load the actual data from Database in onStart. This method should always be called when the user navigates back to this activity.

Comment: Yeah the main problem is how to keep all the activities always showing the new information. If in another activity I make changes to the DB, then when the first activity resumes it will still have to same data showing. I could restart it but what if I click back to go to a previous activity which also needs to be restarted. I don't have a proper way to keep track of this.

Comment: @Tomate_Salat don't get me wrong, but answers should provide more info, than just "use this". Next time try explaining why this solution is better so future viewers with more or less knowledge, find this answer useful.

Comment: @omega have you tried using the onStart-method? This method will also be called if you return back to the activity. Here you can load the data and update the view.

Comment: @FabioAntunes Ok, that make sense, sorry. I will keep this in mind.

Comment: But what if i don't need to actually redownload the data? For example, I clicked cancel in the edit activity.